# Visual Studio too slow to load even a small project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

On the latest version of my `Windows 10 - Pro` my `VS2019 - ver 16.9` takes about `345 second` (more than 5 minutes) to load a a project. For example, a small `ASP.NET MVC Core` project with no database or any other extra tools involved takes about little more than 5 minutes to load. Only one window `Solution Explorer` is used in the solution and that window is auto hide by default. **Question**: What may be causing the slow download of every project and how can the issue be resolved?

**System Environment**:

```
TOSHIBA Satellite C55-A
Processor: Interl Core i3-400 CPU @ 2.40GHz
RAM: 6.00 GB
```

Comment: That CPU seems quite old for VS2019 (which always was quite heavy on resources). Does it happens when opening an empty IDE too? You can also look at task manager to see what resource are you exausting, but most likely you'll need a more powerful computer or a ligther editor.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, it does take significantly long time (about 150 seconds) to open the IDE, as well.

Comment: I would say then that Visual Studio is too much for your computer. Could you try an older version? Or some other IDE? Or is even an option to upgrade the computer?